Creating correlated Gaussian processes
I want to create a set of Gaussian processes that are correlated.
Presently I understand how to generate a Gaussian process using which I am able to generate a sequence of length T. I do this by defining a kernel function that generates a covariance matrix of size TxT and using this I can generate n number of sequence.
Now what I would like is to have some correlation among these n sequences. What I have in mind is to somehow create matrix of size nT x nT using which I can create a sequence of length nT that I can reshape to nxT matrix. But I don't know of any kernel function that would help me achieve this matrix. Morever if n gets really large, then I don't know how to generate my desired sequences.

Is there better way to achieve this instead of constructing a covariance matrix of shape nT x nT?
What are some good examples of kernel functions that generate such a nT x nT covariance matrix.


The terms we are looking for are coregionalisation and co-kriging. These are the "better way". Coregionalisation refers to the modelling of the dependencies between multiple output variables. Co-kriging refers to kriging against multiple, correlated variables simultaneously and allowing information to be shared between them.
Through coregionalisation we can capture the correlations between different outputs of a multi-output Gaussian process. A great (recentish) reference for this is Alvarez et al. (2012) Kernels for Vector-Valued Functions: A Review and in particular the section on "Separable Kernels and Sum of Separable Kernels". Prior to coregionalisation being more generally used as a term, co-kriging was the name of the game, with various degrees of success and various alternatives showing up (e.g. see Dependent Gaussian Processes (2004) by Boyle & Frean).
There are two main coregionalisation paradigms: the Intrinsic Coregionalisation Model (ICM) and the Linear Coregionalisation Model (LCM).  In the linear model of coregionalisation, the outputs are expressed as linear combinations of independent random functions (our GPs). In the intrinsic model of coregionalisation, we assume we are working with a separable coregionalisation kernel, and we can Kronecker product things extensively.  Both PyMC and GPflow have tutorials on coregionalisation and multi-output GPs and I would strongly recommend going through at least one of them. Note that the coregionalisation matrix is now defining our "covariance" as a kernel/covariance structure, as it models both the individual variability of each GP (diagonal elements) and the shared dependencies across GPs (off-diagonal elements).
Finally, to state the obvious: If we just want to generate some GPs samples (and not fit anything), given two GPs $f$ and $g$ with kernels $K_f$ and $K_g$ respectively, we can also manually calculate our cross-covariance manually as: $\text{CCov}(f(x),g(x^\prime))$ $=$ $K_{fg}​(x,x^\prime)$ $=$ $\rho \sqrt{K_{ff}​(x,x) K_{gg}​(x^\prime,x^\prime)}$, $\rho$ being our correlation coefficient. We would then sample from this as if it is a "univariate" GP. This, unfortunately, does not guarantee any particular mathematical properties for our cross-covariance, it is very hard to adequately fit, and we most likely have to regularise a lot just to ensure the new composite covariance matrix $K_{fg}​(x,x^\prime)$ is PSD but... you know, it's a start! :)
If one is serious about this, the 2015 series of lectures on Gaussian Processes by Neil Lawrence is great to start off; he covers Multi-output Gaussian Processes around the middle of the series.
